# The `Exponent` of some expressions with `Sum`

Tags: summation, exponent

Why the following code does not give `T` where T is a positive integer?

```
Exponent[Sum[Subscript[A, i]*f[x]^i, {i, 0, T}], f[x]]
```

or

```
Exponent[ RootReduce[Sum[Subscript[A, i]*f[x]^i, {i, 0, T}]], f[x]]
```

or

```
Exponent[ 
 RootReduce[
  Sum[Subscript[A, i]*f[x]^i + Subscript[B, i]*f[x]^-i, {i, 0, T}]], 
 f[x]]
```

or

```
       Exponent[
 Assuming[T \[Element] PositiveIntegers,  
  Sum[Subscript[A, i]*f[x]^i, {i, 0, T}]] , f[x]]
```

Comment: Note `PolynomialQ[Sum[Subscript[A, i]*f[x]^i, {i, 0, T}], f[x]]` is `False`, probably for similar reasons.

Comment: Maybe "`Exponent` is purely syntactical; it does not attempt to recognize zero coefficients" (from the documentation) could be interpreted as an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @MichaelE2, `Exponent` probably simply isn't powerful enough to handle symbolic `Sum`s.

Assuming your exponent is a monotonic function so that the maximum exponent is well-defined regardless the upper limit, you can define your own `mExponent` which handles simple expressions with one `Sum`.

```
mExponent[Sum[a__, {i_, imin_, imax_}], form_] := 
  Module[{exp = Exponent[a, form], mon},
   mon = FunctionMonotonicity[{exp, i >= imin}, i];
   Switch[mon, 1, exp /. i -> imax, -1, exp /. i -> imin, _, 
    Indeterminate]];
mExponent[args__] := Exponent[args]

mExponent[Sum[a[i] f^i, {i, 0, T}], f]
(* T *)

mExponent[Sum[a[i] f^-i, {i, 0, T}], f]
(* 0 *)

mExponent[Sum[a[i] f^(i + 3)^2, {i, 0, T}], f]
(* (3 + T)^2 *)

mExponent[Sum[a[i] f^(i - 3)^2, {i, 0, T}], f]
(* Indeterminate *)
```